# Included Resources in Swagger

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm writing a REST API using swagger and I'm having trouble defining a easy to read specification that aligns with the jsonapi format (jsonapi.org). The issue is specific to the definition of included resources.

I have multiple included resources all with different attributes.

```
"included": [{
                "type": "author",
                "id": "323454",
                "attributes": {
                  "1": "Bob",
                  "2": "Jim"
                },
              {
                "type": "book",
                "id": "323454",
                "attributes": {
                  "3": "The Island"
                  "4": "The Other Island"
                }]
```

I've tried defining multiple $ref objects under the included array but this doesn't work:

```
  included:
    type: array
    items: 
      - $ref: "#/definitions/includedResource"
      - $ref: "#/definitions/includedResource2"
      - $ref: "#/definitions/includedResource3"
```

Is there nice way to set multiple optional objects? I don't want to call out all attributes in the one resource object as it is not easy to read or align attribute to resource.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenAPI (fka Swagger) 2.0, array items must be of the same type only, e.g. all strings or all `includedResource`.

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, your example can be described using a single schema for `includedResource`, with the `attributes` property being an associative array/dictionary.

```
definitions:
  included:
    type: array
    items:
      $ref: '#/definitions/includedResource'

  includedResource:
    type: object
    # required: [type, id, attributes] # Indicate the required properties if needed
    properties:
      type:
        type: string
        # enum: [author, book] # Use enum if needed
      id:
        type: string
      attributes:
        type: object
        additionalProperties: 
          type: string
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to avoid this format as it means that all of the 'additionalProperties', whether they be properties for the author or book, will be classed the same.

Comment: So you want to be able to define specific `attributes` for `author`, `book`, etc?